# Platzierung des Wortes „nicht“ im Satz

Tags: word-order, negation

Warum sind A1 und B1 anstelle von A2 und B2 richtig?

- A1. Die Bevölkerung ist meistens **nicht** kritisch (richtig)
- A2. Die Bevölkerung ist meistens kritisch **nicht**

- B1. Die Fans haben **nicht** mit einem Sieg gerechnet (richtig)
- B2. Die Fans haben mit einem Sieg **nicht** gerechnet

Comment: Würde es eine andere Bedeutung geben? Die Lösungen sagen A1 und B1, aber ich verstehe sie nicht.

Comment: A2 ist eindeutig falsch. B1 ist normal, aber B2 ist möglich.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Nicht* kann zwei Funktionen erfüllen:

- es negiert ein direkt darauf folgendes Adjektiv oder Substantiv; oder
- es negiert das Verb des Satzes.

Im ersten Fall muss es *direkt vor dem Adjektiv* stehen:

> Die Bevölkerung ist meistens *nicht kritisch*.

*Nicht* bezieht sich hier relativ eindeutig auf das *kritsch*. Der Satz ist quasi positiv formuliert, und schreibt der Bevölkerung die Eigenschaft *unkritisch* zu. Ähnliche Sätze wären:

> Nicht die Bevölkerung ist meistens kritisch.
>
> Kritisch ist die Bevölkerung meistens nicht.
>
> Nicht kritisch ist die Bevölkerung meistens.

Im ersten Fall wird wieder eine Positivaussage getroffen: Jemand oder etwas ist meistens kritisch, aber es ist nicht die Bevölkerung. Im zweiten Fall wird tatsächlich eine Negativaussage getroffen: Der Bevölkerung wird die Eigenschaft *kritisch* abgesprochen. Und zuletzt, im dritten Beispiel wird der Bevölkerung wieder die Eigenschaft *unkritisch* in einer Positivaussage zugewiesen.

Es klingt mindestens unidiomatisch, wenn nicht sogar falsch, das *nicht* in diesem Satz ans Ende zu stellen. Demnach würde auch ich nur A1 als richtige Antwort werten.

---

Im zweiten Beispiel sieht es anders aus. *Nicht* bezieht sich hier **nicht** auf den Sieg, denn dann müsste es heißen:

> Die Fans haben mit *keinem* Sieg gerechnet.

Vielmehr bezieht sich dieses *nicht* auf das Rechnen, also das Verb; es wird also wieder eine Negativaussage getroffen. In diesem Fall hat das *nicht* die Funktion eines Adverbs und kann nahezu frei im Satz umhergeschoben werden. Einige, nicht vollzählige Beispiele:

> Nicht gerechnet haben die Fans mit einem Sieg.
> Die Fans haben nicht mit einem Sieg gerechnet.
> Die Fans haben mit einem Sieg nicht gerechnet.

Zwar haben die beiden letzten Sätze einen *leichten* Unterschied darin, welche Satzglieder sie betonen, ***das sollte aber kein Grund sein, einen von den beiden als falsch anzukreiden!***

Comment: „_Nicht_ bezieht sich hier relativ eindeutig auf das _kritsch_.“ – Dem Teil stimme ich nicht zu. Ein Satz-verneinendes _nicht_ stünde in diesem Beispiel an derselben Stelle und wäre die normale Interpretation, wenn es keine besonderen Hinweise aus Betonung oder Kontext gibt; die andere Interpretation ist natürlich nicht unmöglich, aber ungewöhnlich.

Comment: @chirlu Aus dem normalen Redefluss heraus würde ich den Satz allerdings so intonieren, dass *nicht* und *kritisch* zusammengehörend klingen. Ohne eine große Zahl an Fällen abgeklopft zu haben, würde ich behaupten, dass fast alle verneinten *sein*-Sätze in Wirklichkeit Positivaussagen des Gegenteils sind (wenn kein Substantiv folgt – wobei man auch eher »Ich bin kein Lügner« als »Ich bin nicht ein Lügner« sagt).

Answer (score 1):

Zu den konkreten Beispielen: A1 ist grammatisch (*nicht* negiert *kritisch*). A2 ist ungrammatisch. B1 ist grammatisch (*nicht* negiert *mit einem Sieg*; alternativ kann man auch *mit einem Sieg gerechnet* als die von *nicht* negierte Verbgruppe auffassen). B2 ist ebenfalls grammatisch (*nicht* negiert die Verbgruppe *haben gerechnet*).

Es ist immer riskant, die Grammatik seiner Muttersprache freihändig erklären zu wollen, aber ich versuche es trotzdem. Mir scheint, es gibt nur zwei Punkte, die man bei der Negation mit *nicht* im Deutschen unbedingt verstehen muss.

(1) *Nicht* steht immer vor dem negierten Element.

> *Nicht ich* habe heute das Brot gegessen. (Jemand anders hat das Brot gegessen.)
>
> Ich habe *nicht heute* das Brot gegessen. (Ich habe gestern das Brot gegessen.)
>
> Ich habe heute *nicht das Brot* gegessen. (Ich habe heute den Kuchen gegessen.)
>
> Ich habe heute *nicht das* Brot gegessen. (Ich habe heute dieses (andere) Brot gegessen. - Diese Lesart erfordert eine Betonung auf *das*.)
>
> Ich habe heute das Brot *nicht gegessen*. (Ich habe heute das Brot gebacken.)

(2) In normalen deutschen Hauptsätzen mit dem V2-Satzbau steht das konjugierte Verb an zweiter Stelle (nach dem Subjekt oder einem durch Vorziehen besonders hervorgehobenen Satzteil - z.B. Fragewort) und der Rest der Verbgruppe immer am Ende des Satzes. Man negiert nie das konjugierte Verb selbst, sondern immer den Rest der Verbgruppe. Im Extremfall bedeutet das, dass das Wort *nicht* allein den Teil der Verbgruppe bildet, der am Ende des Satzes steht.

In den folgenden Beispielen ist jeweils die ganze Verbgruppe samt Verneinung kursiv:

> Ich *habe* heute das Brot *nicht gegessen*.
>
> Ich *kann* heute das Brot *nicht essen*.
>
> Ich *esse* heute das Brot *nicht*.

Ohne den bestimmten Artikel verhält sich *Brot essen* wie ein einzelnes Verb, so dass *Brot* kein Objekt sondern Teil der Verbgruppe ist:

> Ich *habe* heute *nicht Brot gegessen*.
>
> Ich *kann* heute *nicht Brot essen*.
>
> Ich esse heute *nicht Brot*.

(Diese Beispiele sind mehrdeutig. Man kann sie auch so lesen, dass nur das Wort *Brot* negiert wird: nicht Brot wird gegessen, sondern z.B. Kuchen.)

Warum die Negation so seltsam erfolgt, dass u.U. das Wort *nicht* ganz allein am Ende des Satzes steht, weit weg vom konjugierten Verb, das es negiert - das kann man verstehen, wenn man sich den ursprünglichen Satzbau anschaut, aus dem V2 hervorgegangen ist. Es gibt ihn heute noch in Nebensätzen.

> Ich sage, dass ich heute das Brot *nicht gegessen habe*.
>
> Ich sage, dass ich heute das Brot *nicht essen kann*.
>
> Ich sage, dass ich heute das Brot *nicht esse*.

V2 bedeutet (im Deutschen - in anderen Sprachen mit V2-Satzbau sind die Details z.T. evt. etwas anders), dass das konjugierte Verb und sonst nichts von der allerletzten Position im Satz zur zweiten Position vorgezogen wird. Damit kommen wir wieder zu den Beispielen von weiter oben:

> Ich *habe* heute das Brot *nicht gegessen*.
>
> Ich *kann* heute das Brot *nicht essen*.
>
> Ich *esse* heute das Brot *nicht*.

Die Negation mit *nicht* ist also ganz logisch. Daneben gibt es noch die wesentlich weniger logische Negation mit *kein*. Sie ist nicht immer möglich, aber wenn sie möglich ist, ist sie oft mehrdeutig und kann für mehrere der anderen Negationen stehen. Sie wird dann auch oft bevorzugt.

---

**Nachtrag zur Betonung:** Weitere Nuancen kann man durch die Betonung ausdrücken. Wenn das Wort *nicht* die stärkste Betonung im Satz erhält, bedeutet das, tendenziell: Die vor dem Wort *nicht* kommenden Teile des Satzes (dazu zählt nie das konjugierte Verb, denn es gilt als Teil der Verbgruppe, die ja erst am Ende kommt) werden nicht abgestritten und sind wahrscheinlich wahr.

Schauen wir uns das in den Beispielen zur Stellung von *nicht* an:

> ***Nicht** ich* habe heute das Brot gegessen.

Diese Betonung ergibt wenig Sinn und kommt so gut wie nicht vor. (Dagegen unterstreicht eine gleich starke Betonung von *nicht* und *ich*, dass jemand anders sehr wohl das Brot gegessen hat.)

> Ich habe ***nicht** heute das Brot gegessen*.

Hier wird nur das Wort *ich* nicht abgestritten. Es hätte ja auch wenig Sinn, meine Existenz abzustreiten.

Diese Betonung macht klar, dass die gesamte Gruppe *heute das Brot gegessen* negiert wird. Ich streite nur die Behauptung ab, ich hätte heute das Brot gegessen. (Vielleicht habe ich es gestern gegessen, oder vielleicht habe ich es heute verschenkt.) Mehr sage ich auf Anraten meines Anwalts nicht.

> Ich habe heute ***nicht** das Brot gegessen*.

Diese Betonung streitet nicht ab, dass heute etwas Relevantes mit mir passiert ist. (Vielleicht habe ich heute den Kuchen gegessen, oder vielleicht habe ich gesehen, wie jemand anders das Brot gegessen hat.) Was heute nicht passiert ist, ist, dass ich das Brot gegessen habe. Falls ich das Brot gestern gegessen haben sollte, könnte ich den Satz so sagen, um subtil einen Ermittler auf die falsche Fährte zu locken - er soll untersuchen, was sich heute abgespielt hat.

> Ich habe heute das Brot ***nicht** gegessen*.

Ich streite nicht ab, dass heute (oder an einem anderen Tag) etwas mit dem Brot passiert ist, oder das ich heute (oder an einem anderen Tag) etwas getan habe. Vielleicht habe ich sogar gestern oder heute das Brot weggeworfen. Ich streite lediglich die Behauptung ab, ich hätte heute das Brot gegessen und verweigere ansonsten die Mitwirkung bei der Aufklärung.

Wenn statt *nicht* etwas anderes betont wird, dann handelt es sich immer um das abgestrittene Element des Satzes. Dabei können dann durchaus auch mal Betonung und Satzbau scheinbar im Widerspruch stehen, was aber dazu dienen kann, besondere Nuancen auszudrücken. Beispiel:

> Ich habe **heute** *nicht das Brot* gegessen.

Ich habe nicht das Brot gegessen, sondern den Kuchen. Allerdings gilt mein Abstreiten nur für heute. An anderen Tagen habe ich durchaus auch mal das Brot gegessen.

Comment: Es hängt auch von der Betonung ab: Für mich besteht etwa ein Unterschied zwischen "Ich habe das Brot *nicht* gegessen" und "Ich habe das Brot nicht *gegessen*".

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Das ist richtig, scheint aber nur eine zusätzliche Nuance zu ergeben. Die Betonung zeigt in diesem Fall an, ob man die Verbgruppe stellvertretend für den ganzen Satz negiert (*nicht* betont: Es ist nicht wahr, dass ich das Brot gegessen habe) oder ob man nur das Verb selbst abstreitet (*gegessen* betont: Ich habe das Brot nicht gegessen, sondern weggeworfen, weil es verschimmelt war). Ich schaue mal, ob ich das noch sinnvoll einfügen kann.